# How would I reduce the Minimum Vertex Cover problem to a Weighted MAX SAT problem?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, satisfiability

I am currently trying to solve the Minimum Vertex Cover problem via a Weighted MAX SAT solver, but I am stuck with the model. The transformation to a simple SAT is straightforward since every node can be a variable and every edge a clause with a disjunction between start and end node, but I have a problem introducing the minimum boundary. I thought of adding clauses with each just containing a negated variable in order to inhibit that simply all variables are set to true. But this does not work in all instances. Could you hint me on how I could construct that?

Comment: It doesn't work because all the covering clauses must be satisfied, while the unit clauses may be unsatisfied.  Anything you can do with the weights?

Comment: That was exactly my problem. That's why I thought that playing with the clause weights may create an equivalent for the minimum constraint. But I am not exactly sure how.

Comment: Make the weight of a "mandatory" clause large enough that it outweighs all "optional" clauses together.